# Modifying a CSV file and adding a new calculated column?

Tags: windows, powershell, csv

I have a CSV file that has fixed number of columns, the first record is always the column field names followed by the data. I want to append a new calculated column, for the new column calculation - I want to call `Invoke-WebRequest` passing in data from an existing field and store the returned data as the appended field value.

Example of existing log.csv file:

```
date,time,User,Page,Client-IP,X-Forwarded-For,Server-IP
2017-12-11,16:54:48,user@domain.com,/owa/test.html,111.111.111.111,222.222.222.222,121.121.121.121
2017-12-11,16:54:48,user@domain.com,/owa/test.html,222.222.222.222,222.222.222.222,111.111.111.121
```

For each record in the CSV file, I want to take the X-Forwarded-For field data and call `Invoke-WebRequest` as follows:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:6779/json/222.222.222.222 |
    Select -Expand Content |
    ConvertFrom-Json |
    Select -ExpandProperty country_name
```

In the above cmd, 222.222.222.222 is the X-Forwarded-For data for the first record. The returned data is going to be the country name.

I would imagine the code to be...

```
$GEOIP = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:6779/json/$($OWAHTTPLog).X-Forwarded-For |
         Select -Expand Content |
         ConvertFrom-Json |
         Select -ExpandProperty country_name
$OWAHTTPLog = Import-Csv C:\owalog.csv |
              Select *,@{Name='GEOIP-Country';Expression={"$GEOIP"}} |
              Export-Csv C:\audit.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The issue is, I need to grab the value of X-Forwarded-For from the CSV and pass that to the `Invoke-WebRequest` as `$IPAddress`? how does one do that in the example I have?

Comment: The expression code scriptblock can be a function or a script.

Comment: Added more context to my original question, how do I pass value from CSV file to the Expression?

Comment: You would use the `$_` variable to refer to the current object. (See `help Select-Object -Full` for more details about calculated properties.)

Comment: Can you show an example? As I said I've spent quite some time on this and I can't seem to wrap my head around it. it is starting to hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other method:

```
import-csv 'C:\owalog.csv' | %{
$row=$_
$uri = 'http://localhost:6779/json/{0}' -f $row.'X-Forwarded-For';
$Result=(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri).Content | ConvertFrom-Json | Select -ExpandProperty country_name
$row | Add-Member -Name 'GEOIP-Country' -Value $Result -MemberType NoteProperty
$row

} | Export-Csv 'C:\audit.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: This worked for what I needed, thank you for the example.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the property from which you want to derive the value of the new column in the expression of the [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```
Import-Csv 'C:\owalog.csv' |
    Select *,@{n='GEOIP-Country';e={
        $uri = 'http://localhost:6779/json/{0}' -f $_.'X-Forwarded-For';
        (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri).Content | ConvertFrom-Json |
            Select -ExpandProperty country_name
    }} |
    Export-Csv 'C:\audit.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: This looks like it would work, but I ended up going with Esperento57 sample. Thanks for posting.